# In Laravel 5.6 there are new UUID Methods, How do I use them?

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

In Laravel 5.6 a couple of new `UUID` methods were added under this package

`use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

If I do something like this: `dd(Str::uuid());`

I get the following output:

```
DegradedUuid {#215 ▼
  #codec: StringCodec {#217 ▼
    -builder: DegradedUuidBuilder {#218 ▼
      -converter: DegradedNumberConverter {#221}
    }
  }
  #fields: array:6 [▼
    "time_low" => "fbf262eb"
    "time_mid" => "e1a3"
    "time_hi_and_version" => "43f4"
    "clock_seq_hi_and_reserved" => "b1"
    "clock_seq_low" => "2f"
    "node" => "7be1b2e7490f"
  ]
  #converter: DegradedNumberConverter {#221}
}
```

I've never used UUID before but I am trying to create a test email verification / confirmation authentication. I did a bit of Googling and I thought I was supposed to get a string like this: `fbf262eb-e1a3-43f4-b1-2f-7be1b2e7490f`

And then store it in my DB and go from there. Where am I not understanding this or going wrong with this?

Additionally, I read through this post to try and understand what an UUID is [What is a UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292965/what-is-a-uuid)

But how do I use these new methods?

Comment: UUIDs are apparently objects in Laravel. Check the documentation; it should tell you how to get a string like you're used to seeing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method returns an object, if you wish to access the value directly then cast it to a string, e.g:

```
$uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-uuid

Comment: In fact it should be done with ```Str::uuid()->toString()``` using the method available in the Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface (at least in Laravel 5.6) to follow what the interface promises.

Comment: By just simply casting the UUID object didn't work for me. toString() function did the trick! Thanks @AdrianHernandez-Lopez

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez magic methods should not be accessed directly: the purpose of `__toString` is to allow you to cast an object to a string, using `__toString` directly means you aren't casting the object to a string, you're asking the object to provide a value.