# Best way to use some unique value for CRUD operations without id - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm asking you because i didn't found somewhere best way to use some unique value for CRUD operations without using id into PHP application. It's about one table which contain more data from different users, and i don't want to show id which entry data belongs another user.

I thought of using a new column named "hash" and this hash i putted on form with hidden input. I'm using Laravel framework. Or it's good to use uuid and cuid? Can someone tell me if my solution is the best or if exist a better solution, please?

Best regards,
Alexandru

Answer (score 0):

There will be many ways to do this, but my approach for this solution is [uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292965/what-is-a-uuid) ( universally unique identifier) you can use it as a primary key and also use the auto-generating [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid) to generate a unique UUID